# Symfony2 - validating additional form elements

Tags: symfony, logic, constraints

How can I validate additional form fields that do not exist in my entity and are not even related to them?

For example: A user needs to accept the rules so I can add an additional checkbox with mapping set to false but how can I add a constraint which validates this field?

Or even more advanced: A user needs to repeat his e-mail AND password in the form correctly. How can I validate that they're the same?

I want to avoid adding these fields in my entity because it's not related in any way.

I use Symfony 2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to hang constraints directly on the form element.  For example:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $notBlank = new NotBlank();

    $builder->add('personFirstName', 'text', array('label' => 'AYSO First Name', 'constraints' => $notBlank));
    $builder->add('personLastName',  'text', array('label' => 'AYSO Last Name',  'constraints' => $notBlank));
```

For the repeating stuff, look at the repeated element: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html

Another approach to validation would be to create a wrapper object for you entity.  The wrapper object would contain the additional unrelated properties.  You could then set your constraints in validation.yml instead of directly on the form.

Finally, you could build a form type just for one property and add the constraints to it:

```
class EmailFormType extends AbstractType
{
public function getParent() { return 'text'; }
public function getName()   { return 'cerad_person_email'; }

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'label'           => 'Email',
        'attr'            => array('size' => 30),
        'required'        => true,
        'constraints'     => array(
            new Email(array('message' => 'Invalid Email')), 
        )
    ));
}
}
```